# How do I open multiple message boxes in vbs?

Tags: vbscript, modal-dialog, message, msgbox

I know that if you input

```
Do

msgbox("This is a msg box")

loop
```

Then a msg box pops up that won't go away.

I want multiple message boxes that you ARE able to close.

How do I do this?

Comment: You cannot do this in vanilla VBScript, why do you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look for non-modal dialogs. The msgbox that you pop-up here are modal, that's why they come one after the other (execution is suspended while the dialog is open).

You will find references for this on the web.

```
Func _NoHaltMsgBox($code=0, $title = "",$text = "" ,$timeout = 0)
  Run (@AutoItExe & ' /AutoIt3ExecuteLine  "MsgBox(' & $code & ', '''& $title & ''', '''& $text &''',' & $timeout & ')"')
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: You're probably going to encounter severe lag and or crashing. I am not held responsible of any damages if you choose to continue.**

You can make a batch file that opens the same VBS script many times.
Make a notepad with:

```
msgbox("YourTextHere")
```

Or if you want to loop it:

```
do
msgbox("YourTextHere")
loop
```

Replace YourTextHere with whatever you want.

Then save it as .vbs

then make another notepad:

```
start "MessageBox" "MessageBox.vbs"
```

Change "MessageBox" with the name of the message box VBS you made.

Copy and paste the same script multiple times to open it more times **(Do this at your own risk, you may encounter severe lag).**

Then save it as .bat

Or add the batch file itself multiple times so it can create a loop of opening batch files which can open more scripts out of them. **(Do this at your own risk, you may encounter severe lag).**

For example:

```
start "BatchFile" "Batchfile.bat"
```

Change "BatchFile" with the name of the Batchfile you made.

Copy and paste it multiple times to open it more times again **(Do this at your own risk, you may encounter severe lag).**

**So far, you're okay since you did not open the .bat file. IF you try testing it, It'll open multiple instances of your .bat file and the message box, then open more instances off the new instances, then more instances off the even newer instances, and repeat enough to make your PC crash or lag.**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a batch file, try this: 
**Step 1 - the error message** 
Let's say you wanted `a=msgbox("messageboxtext")`. So, in Notepad, you would write `a=msgbox("messageboxtext")` and save it as a .vbs file. 
**Step 2 - the spammer** 
*Infinitely* 
In a new Notepad document, paste this:

```
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
count = "hello world"
do until count = 1
shell.run("""C:\Users\user\Documents\error.vbs""")
loop
```

Replace C:\Users\user\Documents\error.vbs with the location of the file. Save it as a .vbs file.
*Finitely*
To open a finite number of windows, use this code:

```
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
count = 0
do until count = 5
shell.run("""C:\Users\user\Documents\error.vbs""")
loop
```

Replace the 5 with the number of times you would like the message to spawn. 
 Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

You need a multiple button `MsgBox`, set it as a value then: if `CANCEL` is pressed, the process will stop.

```
Do
spam=MsgBox("SPAM",3)
If spam = 2 Then
WScript.Quit
End If
Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First make an File called "anything.vbs" replace anything with anything you want.
2. Then Edit it and Put in the Code

```
msgbox("LOL")
loop"
```

3. Replace LOL with anything you Like.
4. Then make a .bat File.
5. Put in the Code

```
start "LOL.bat"
loop"
```

Now you have a Spammer. :)